# Javascript - How to hide a drop down control if it's empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a cascade dropdown on a form. User selects Document Type and most of the document type has Category. However, if a doc type does not have category then I would like to hide the category drop down. Is there a way to see if category dropdown (calculate array or something) and hide category control (by default it always show Select a value even if the drop down does not have any value to select from)

So far I have following and wondering how to evaluate category drop down control based on what user selected in the doc type drop down control.

```
NWF$(document).ready(function(){  
     var varDocType= NWF$('#' + jsDocTypes)// gets Doc Type control;
     varDocType.change(function(){  
          if(this.value !== null){  
            alert(varDocType.val());
            var varCategory = NWF$('#' + jsCategory)// gets Category control;
            alert(varCategory.val());
            if(varCategory == ''){
              NWF$('#' + jsCategory).style.visibility = "hidden";

           }
          }  

     });  
});
```

Comment: You could query for `option` elements and if the length was == 0 then that would indicate the select element for the dropdown was empty.

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

```css
select:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
Invisible: ||<select></select>--<br>
Visible (whitespace): ||<select> </select>--<br>
Visible (children): ||<select><option>Options!</option></select>--
```

I do not know what is **NWF$** but if you want hide an element by javascript:

```
TheElement.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: I had never heard of the `:empty` psudo-class. Probably best to be clear about the limitations (namely, whitespace counts):https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: Actually, this did not help. I put an alert where category has 5 items and it shows blank. I need JS to evaluate category bucket because it changes based on Doc Type. Then only hide if drop down array is empty.

Comment: @Fuji-H2O - Are you hiding an element based on an array that's unrelated to it? Or based on an "array" of it's children `option`s?

Comment: user does not want to see Category if a certain document type does not have categories. that's why I have to count or evaluate and hide it if category dropdown did not populate any values