# How to hide elements from a dropdown menu based on other values?

Tags: javascript, css

UPDATE

I am working on SharePoint and Nintex Form which allows embedding JS into the form but uses NWF$ instances e.g. (NWF$('#' + varConcept) see an example here [Javascript - How to hide a drop down control if it's empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904612/javascript-how-to-hide-a-drop-down-control-if-its-empty)

I have now created a question in the [sharepoint section](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271649/how-to-hide-elements-from-a-dropdown-menu-based-on-other-values)

There is a fieldname (not a dropdown) named `varConcept` and may contain values such as `Pending`, `In Review`, `Accepted`, `In Work`.

There is a dropdown menu named `varConcept` which holds following options: Updated, Reviewed, Already Implemented, Duplicate, Assigned and the idea behind all this is to make a script that checks the varStatus and shows relevant options in the dropdown box aka. varConcept.

In simple context:

```
IF varStatus contains "Pending" then show varConcept options Updated and Duplicate
IF varStatus contains "In Review" then show varConcept options Reviewed and Already Implemented
IF varStatus contains "Accepted" then show varConcept options Assigned
else hide everything
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, this question maybe should have been in SharePont.StackExchange page. Can this be migrated over?

Comment: Please share the code that you already have..

Comment: @Narayanan I don't have a code ... it is sharepont + Nintex form which can use javascript and css to do the work, hence why I am here to get some help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and errors, I got it working

```
   NWF$(document).ready(function() { 
   if (NWF$('#' + varStatus).val() == 'Pending' )
    {
      NWF$("#"+ varConcept).find("option[value='Pending']").remove();
      NWF$("#"+ varConcept).find("option[value='Reviewed']").remove();      
    }
   if (NWF$('#' + varStatus).val() == 'In Review' )
    {
      NWF$("#"+ varConcept).find("option[value='Pending']").remove();
      NWF$("#"+ varConcept).find("option[value='Updated']").remove();
       }
   });
```

There is no other else if to say "anything outside the above, hide everything" but if you have the answer, feel free to add a comment.

Comment: "anything outside the above, hide everything"
you could do this by using if(){}else if(){} else{ // hide everything here }

Or you could place a return in each if(){} block and hide everything at the bottom of your ready() function. It would only reach there if none of the 2 if() conditions are met.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the dropdown using javascript and based on the status you create the dropdown options.

```js
   var currentStatus = 'Reviewed'; // load the current status of the dropdown
   var div = document.querySelector("#container"),
       frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
       select = document.createElement("select");

       if (currentStatus === 'Accepted') {
           select.options.add(new Option("Rejected", "Rejected"));
       } else if (currentStatus === 'Reviewed') {
           select.options.add(new Option("Accepted", "Accepted", true, true));
           select.options.add(new Option("Rejected", "Rejected"));
       } else if (currentStatus === 'Rejected') {
           select.options.add(new Option("Accepted", "Accepted", true, true));
       }

       frag.appendChild(select);
       div.appendChild(frag);
```

```html
   <div id="container">

    </div>
```

Comment: would the above be compatible using the NWF$ as I am using sharepoint and Nintex which does not work with the above ... :/

Comment: right, but I cannot use div id as the dropdown field has an JS ID set to 'varConcept' and it would be something like NWF$('#' + varConcet) see this topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904612/javascript-how-to-hide-a-drop-down-control-if-its-empty which is similar but need some modification to fit my purpose

Comment: Then assign `var div = NWF$('#' + varConcet)`. Replace the second line with this. Hope this will work.

Comment: see my new topic https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271649/how-to-hide-elements-from-a-dropdown-menu-based-on-other-values

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Since your question is not completed with information like what is ***Status*** and how we are getting the `value` of ***Status***.

Let us assume you are getting the `value` of ***Status*** from some API you build and your HTML is below

```
<ul>
    <li class="myClass" id="accepted">Accepted</li>
    <li class="myClass" id="reviewed">Reviewed</li>
    <li class="myClass" id="rejected">Rejected</li>
    <li class="myClass" id="already-done">Already Done</li>
<ul>
```

Step 1: Using CSS hide all the elements of your dropdown.
Example:

```
.myClass{
 display: none;
}
```

Step 2: Now lets use JavaScript to show and hide elements based on ***Status*** variable value.

```
switch(Status) {
 case "Pending":
    document.getElementById("reviewed").style.display = "block;
    break;

 case "Accepted":
    document.getElementById("accepted").style.display = "block;
    break; 

 case "Rejected":
    document.getElementById("rejected").style.display = "block;
    break;

 case "Already Done":
    document.getElementById("already-Done").style.display = "block;
    break;    
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, this question should have been in SharePoint.Stackoverflow as it uses NWF$ syntax ... and I am noob in coding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "onchange" event to the select.

When the selection changes, you can hide/show options as you wish. This can be done based on the selected value.

```js
const filterOptions = (e) => {
 const selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  for(const option of e.options){
  option.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
  
  // always hide the initial "select one" option
  e.options[5].classList.add('hidden');
  
  if(selectedValue === 'pending'){
   e.options[1].classList.add('hidden');
    e.options[3].classList.add('hidden');
    e.options[4].classList.add('hidden');
  }
  

}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="dropdown" onchange="filterOptions(this)">
  <option value="pending">Pending</option>
  <option value="accepted">Accepted</option>
  <option value="reviewed">Reviewed</option>
  <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
  <option value="already_done">Already Done</option>
  <option id="initial" selected >Select one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: please see my topic here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271649/how-to-hide-elements-from-a-dropdown-menu-based-on-other-values

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know everyone is giving you code options, because you did ask about code, but honestly, since this is in SharePoint with a Nintex Form, you can do this entirely without code.

Create a List in SharePoint that contains two columns. One column for the test values (pending, in review, accepted) and a second column for the answers (updated, reviewed, duplicate, assigned).

On the form, add a List Lookup control. Use the Filter section to point it to your varStatus control.

Comment: thanks and indeed 'List Lookup' would be perfect but in my case it had already over 150 items and I needed to implement this change due to "human errors" etc. so yeh, I had no chance to use list lookup but to improvise on the current case.  thanks though :)

Comment: I completely understand. You can only do so much with what you have in time and resources. Whenever I build something myself, I try to make it as scalable and easy to maintain as possible. I really like using list lookups, because then the end users can add/change the options whenever they like without requiring my help.

Comment: indeed that is what I also try to avoid issues down the line ... however, when this started it was pretty clear who needs to do what but USERS can be pathetic and as such the worklow was not build to cover all possible loopwholes etc. hence I needed this code to hide options at various stages and I figured it out :) cheers